# RStudio doesn't import R_USER_LIBS from environment

Tags: environment-variables, rstudio

I have exported `R_LIBS_USER` in my `.bashrc` file, but when I open RStudio and do `Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER")` it still uses the defult one (located in my home folder).

How can I have RStudio import variables from the environment?

Comment: Your *.bashrc* is only read by an interactive Bash shell. If you start RStudio in any way other than from an interactive Bash shell the env vars you export from your *.bashrc* won't be present. Depending on your OS one solution is to put the var in */etc/environment*.

Comment: @KurtisRader But on my system my `$HOME/.bash_profile` file, which is sourced for login shells, thus including the one on which the system is run, source `$HOME/.bashrc`

Comment: Again, you seem to misunderstand how the Bash startup scripts work. The *~/.bash_login* script is only sourced when you start an interactive login shell. So, again, unless you're starting RStudio from an interactive Bash prompt those startup scripts are not relevant. I'm guessing you're running RStudio by clicking a desktop icon or selecting it from an app menu shown by your desktop manager. The desktop GUI will not have been started by an interactive (login or otherwise) Bash shell and thus those dot files are not relevant.

Comment: @Kurtis Rader. You are right. I was talking about `$HOME/.bash_profile`, which I thought was read also by non-interactive login shell, i.e. the one that starts the whole system, but that doesn't seem to be the case.